# Getting error of Web Server not configure correnctly while run DotnetNuke Project in VS 2015

Tags: iis, visual-studio-2015, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module, dotnetnuke-7

I have created a DotnetNuke Project. It is working fine if I import .zip file of it as a Module in DotnetNuke.

But if I run the project in any browser, it keep throws following error. I am trying to get rid since few days but still not get any solution. :(

> Unable to start debugging on the web server. The web server is not
>   configured correctly. See help for common configuration erros. Running
>   the web page ourside of the debugger may provide further information.

I have configure Start `http://dnndev.me/` and Project Url to `http://dnndev.me/desktopmodules/MyTest2`

Can anybody please suggest me.

```
After set Debugger = True in web.config file of dnndev.me
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is open the WEB.CONFIG file in the root of the DNN website and make sure that debug is set to true.

Comment: There is no `WEB.CONFIG` file in explorer. I have added explorer screenshot. Can you please take a look and suggest?

Comment: You need to look in the root of the WEBSITE. Do you have the module in a location like c:\websites\dnndev.me\desktopmodules\mytest2\ ?

Comment: Yes. It is located in different drive(f:\websites\dnndev.me\desktopmodules\mytest2\). I think it is not problem, right? I can buid and add module in dnndev.me. It is working perfectly. But sometime I need to debug the event.

Comment: I have added config file manually and set Debut to True. But still same error.

Comment: You need to adjust the web.config file in f:\websites\dnndev.me\ 

not the file in the desktopmodules folder

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. I have done as you suggested. There are some dialogs keep pop up and show error in site. I have edited my question and added screeshot. Plz suggest.